# How to use db.readRows to query each element of an Array that is acquired as part of the payload response?

Tags: arrays, database, testing, karate

Scenario: check a first attribute value is stored in DB after a post method

```
    * request payload
    * method POST
    * status 200
```

## checks in DB for the 1st element in the array

```
    * def rows = db.readRows('select *  from Database.tablename  WHERE attribute_1 = \'' + response.samples[0].toUpperCase().replaceAll('-', '') + '\' ') [0]
    * print rows.attribute1
    * rows.attribute1 contains response.samples[0]
```

. # further validations to match the response with rows.
.
.
.

How can I modify this so that the db.readRows can be run against all the transformed array responses fetched from the POST method

that is to run the database for response.samples[0],[1],[2]... and so on... because the the length of the array also keeps changing

The response payload looks like follows, (Note: it will keep changing each time the POST method is performed):

{
"samples": [
"28728jjd-jj22-jkj2k-2kol2k2",
"28728jjd-jj22-jkj2k-2kol2k1",
"28728jjd-jj22-jkj2k-2kol2k3",
"28728jjd-jj22-jkj2k-2kol2k4",
"28728jjd-jj22-jkj2k-2kol2k5"
]
}

rows will be printed like follows:
[
"28728JJDJJ22JKJ2K2KOL2K2"
]

Comment: see linked answer. get used to loops in karate.